# Проблема с применением фильтра для текстового файла C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Дали задание в университете:
[image: Задание]

[image: Задание1]

Практически всё доделал, однако не пойму, как выполнить условие, при котором выводиться будут только семена, которые можно высаживать с марта по май. Решил сделать для этого отдельный пункт в меню (чтобы при его выборе выводились как раз именно эти семена), пытался написать для него отдельную функцию Seasonality(), но ничего не получилось.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

bool WorkFile = true;

void InputFile(string* output_file)
{
    fstream file("C:\\Это папка\\4 задание.bin");
    string input;
    while (getline(file, input))
    {
        *output_file += input;
        if ('\n')
            * output_file += '\n';
    }
    file.close();
}


void View()
{
    string* str = new string();
    InputFile(str);
    cout << *str << endl;
}

void Adding()
{
    string* str = new string();
    string AddStr, EditStr, NewPar, NewFile;
    InputFile(str);
    AddStr = *str;
    AddStr += '\0';
    int lengthStr = AddStr.length();
    cout << "Введите новый пункт : " << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthStr; i++)
    {
        if (AddStr[i] != '*')
            EditStr += AddStr[i];
        if (AddStr[i] == '*')
        {
            cout << EditStr << " ";
            getline(cin, NewPar);
            EditStr += " ";
            EditStr += NewPar;
            int len = NewPar.length();
            if (len <= 5)
            {
                EditStr += '\t';
                EditStr += '\t';
                EditStr += '\t';
            }
            else
            {
                EditStr += '\t';
                EditStr += '\t';
            }
            EditStr += '|';
            EditStr += '*';
            EditStr += '\0';
            int length_editStr = EditStr.length();
            for (int k = 0; k < length_editStr; k++)
            {
                NewFile += EditStr[k];
            }
            EditStr.clear();
        }
    }
    ofstream file1("C:\\Это папка\\4 задание.bin");
    file1 << NewFile;
    file1.close();
}

void Delete()
{
    string* str = new string();
    string Delete, EditStr, NewFile;
    int DeletePar, DeleteColumn = 0;
    InputFile(str);
    Delete = *str;
    Delete += '\0';
    int length_editStr = Delete.length();
    cout << "Введите номер пункта, который необходимо удалить : ";
    cin >> DeletePar;
    for (int i = 0; i < length_editStr; i++)
    {
        if (Delete[i] != '|')
            EditStr += Delete[i];
        if (Delete[i] == '|')
        {
            DeleteColumn++;
            if (DeleteColumn == DeletePar)
                EditStr = "";
            else
            {
                NewFile += EditStr;
                NewFile += '|';
                EditStr.clear();
            }
        }
        if (Delete[i] == '\n')
            DeleteColumn = 0;
        if (i == length_editStr - 1)
            NewFile += '*';
    }
    ofstream File("C:\\Это папка\\4 задание.bin");
    File << NewFile;
    File.close();
}

void Edit()
{
    string* str = new string();
    string Str, EditPunct, EdStr, NewFile;
    InputFile(str);
    Str = *str;
    Str += '\0';
    int LenStr = Str.length();
    int EdPunct, EdColumn = 1;
    cout << "Введите номер пункта, который необходимо изменить(Если словочетание, слова отделять знаком '.' ) : ";
    cin >> EdPunct;
    for (int i = 0; i < LenStr; i++)
    {
        if (Str[i] != '|')
        {
            if (Str[i] == '\n')
            {
                EdColumn = 1;
                NewFile += EdStr;
                NewFile += '*';
                EdStr.clear();
            }
            EdStr += Str[i];
        }
        if (Str[i] == '|')
        {
            EdColumn++;
            EdStr += '|';
            EdStr += " ";
            i++;
            if (EdColumn == EdPunct)
            {
                cout << EdStr << " ";
                cin >> EditPunct;
                EdStr += EditPunct;
                int len = EditPunct.length();
                if (len <= 8)
                {
                    EdStr += '\t';
                    EdStr += '\t';
                }
                else
                    EdStr += '\t';
                EdStr += '|';
                while (Str[i] != '|') i++;
            }
        }
    }
    ofstream File("C:\\Это папка\\4 задание.bin");
    File << NewFile;
    File.close();
}

void AddString()
{
    string* str = new string();
    string Str, EdStr;
    InputFile(str);
    Str = *str;
    int NumPunct = 0;
    for (int i = 0; Str[i] != '*'; i++)
    {
        if (Str[i] == '|')
            NumPunct++;
        else
            continue;
    }
    for (int k = 1; k <= NumPunct; k++)
    {
        cout << "Введите пункт " << k << " : ";
        cin >> EdStr;
        Str += EdStr;
        Str += '\t';
        Str += '|';
        if (k == NumPunct)
            Str += '*';
        Str += " ";
    }
    ofstream File("C:\\Это папка\\4 задание.bin");
    File << Str;
    File.close();
}

void DeleteString()
{
    string* str = new string();
    string Str, EdStr, NewFile;
    InputFile(str);
    Str = *str;
    Str += '\0';
    int len = Str.length();
    int DelPunct, NumPunct = 1;
    cout << "Введите номер строки, которую необходимо удалить: " << endl;
    cin >> DelPunct;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        EdStr += Str[i];
        if (Str[i] == '*')
        {
            if (NumPunct == DelPunct)
                DelPunct = 0;
            else if (NumPunct != DelPunct)
            {
                NewFile += EdStr;
            }
            EdStr.clear();
            NumPunct++;
        }
    }
    ofstream File("C:\\Это папка\\4 задание.bin");
    File << NewFile;
    File.close();
}

void Seasonality()
{
    ifstream file("C:\\Это папка\\4 задание.bin");
    string* str = new string();
    string Str, Mart, April, May, EditStr;
    Mart = "Март", April = "Апрель", May = "Май";
    int lMart, lApril, lMay;
    lMart = Mart.length();
    lApril = April.length();
    lMay = May.length();
    InputFile(str);
    Str = *str;
    Str += '\0';
    int len = Str.length();
    int Cout = 1, NumStr = 0;

    if (len = lMart)
    {
        InputFile(str);
        cout << *str << endl;
    }
    else if (len = lApril)
    {
        InputFile(str);
        cout << *str << endl;
    }
    else if (len = lMay)
    {
        InputFile(str);
        cout << *str << endl;
    }
}


void Menu()
{
    fstream Menu("C:\\Это папка\\Меню.txt");
    string output, OMenu, menu;
    while (getline(Menu, output))
    {
        OMenu += output;
        if ('\n')
            OMenu += '\n';
    }
    Menu.close();
    cout << OMenu << endl;
    cout << "Введите пункт меню : ";
    getline(cin, menu);
    cout << endl << endl;
    if (menu == "Выход")
        WorkFile = false;
    else if (menu == "Просмотр")
        View();
    else if (menu == "Добавление пункта")
        Adding();
    else if (menu == "Удаление пункта")
        Delete();
    else if (menu == "Добавление строки")
        AddString();
    else if (menu == "Удаление строки")
        DeleteString();
    else if (menu == "Корректировка данных")
        Edit();
    else if (menu == "Сезон Март-Май")
        Seasonality();
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    while (WorkFile)
    {
        Menu();
    }
}
```

Результат работы программы:
[image: Работа программы]
[image: Работа программы(1)]

Answer (score 0):

Вы не думали реорганизовать код? на данный момент у вас все действия ведутся на уровне работы с файлом. Но можно перейти к простейшей схеме данные-представление.
Т.е. вы считываете информацию из файла в массив/вектор структур (каждая структура содержит в себе название, месяц высадки, количество семян и т.п.). А в дальнейшем вы работаете уже не напрямую с файлом, а с этим вектором, а по окончании работы вы сохраняете свой вектор в файл, чтобы все сделанные изменения сохранились на жестком диске. Такой подход значительно упростит многие рутинные операции, типа добавления, удаления, поиска по полю и т.п.

Теперь по теме.
у вас ошибка в операции сравнения `if (len = lMart)` и далее в блоке условий, вместо сравнения вы делаете присваивание

```
void Seasonality()
{
    ...

    if (len == lMart)
    {
        InputFile(str);
        cout << *str << endl;
    }
    ...
}
```

Однако это не решит проблему вывода, т.к. (насколько я понимаю код) вы сравниваете длину месяца с длиной строки, которая считывается из файла, а надо искать нужные вам месяцы...

Comment: Ну и как в таком случае исправить проблему? С векторами работал лишь пару раз, поэтому ещё слишком плохого представления о них, а в массивах не смог всё это организовать (не работали такие функции как добавление или удаление пункта/строки при работе с ними).